# Raspberry pi custom domain in LAN

Tags: ubuntu, lan, webserver, raspberry-pi, raspbian

I have been trying to find solution to this and have been following many articles online. Still I can't be able to achieve the goal. Here is what I wanted open **rpi.dev** in browser of any of the devices connected to my LAN. Here is my scenario:

I have wifi router (MI router 3C)

I assigned Static IP addresses to following devices-

```
Raspberry pi (web server): 192.168.31.164
Ubuntu Laptop: 192.168.31.169
android phone 1: 192.168.31.128
```

Other than static IP address devices there are some other devices such as PC(running on window 7) and other smart phones (androids) that are assigned IP addresses dynamically by router (i.e their IP address keep changing).

I'm using wifi dongle in raspberry pi and I'm able to access it via ssh from ubuntu terminal

I installed LAMP server in Raspberry pi, I added a custom domain **rpi.dev** in /etc/hosts and able to see webpages (I also installed wordpress at rpi.dev).

The contents of /etc/hosts is as follow:

```
127.0.0.1       localhost
::1             localhost ip6-localhost ip6-loopback
ff02::1         ip6-allnodes
ff02::2         ip6-allrouters

127.0.1.1       raspberrypi
192.168.31.164  rpi.dev
```

Next when in Ubuntu system, I added added the domain rpi.dev with raspberry pi ip address i.e

```
192.168.31.164    rpi.dev
```

By this Im able to see the wordpress site of raspberry pi device rpi.dev in ubuntu system browser.

Since we can't be able to edit hosts file in android system unless we root it, which I don't want to do. So in this case I can't open the domain rpi.dev in smartphones browser. So I followed [this article](https://superuser.com/questions/769207/set-up-a-website-on-my-internal-network-and-access-it-with-a-domain-name-instead) and subsequently [another article link](http://ulyssesonline.com/2007/11/07/how-to-setup-a-dns-server-in-ubuntu/) from the first article.

By following the above 2 links, I installed Bind9 and the contents of the following files is as follow:

***/etc/bind/named.conf.local***

```
/
// Do any local configuration here
//

// Consider adding the 1918 zones here, if they are not used in your
// organization
//include "/etc/bind/zones.rfc1918";

#raspberry pi domain zone
zone "rpi.dev"{
        type master;
        file "/etc/bind/zones/rpi.dev.db";
};

#for reverse DNS
zone "31.168.192.in-addr.arpa" {
        type master;
        file "/etc/bind/zones/rev.31.168.192.in-addr.arpa";
};
```

***/etc/bind/zones/rpi.dev.db***

```
$TTL 3D
@ IN SOA ns.rpi.dev. admin.rpi.dev. (
   2007062001
   28800
   3600
   604800
   38400
);
rpi.dev.  IN      NS         ns.rpi.dev.
ubuntudesktop  IN      A          192.168.31.169
www            IN      CNAME      ubuntudesktop
miphone        IN      A          192.168.31.128
gw             IN      A          192.168.31.1
                       TXT        "Network Gateway"
```

***/etc/bind/zones/rev.31.168.192.in-addr.arpa***

```
$TTL 3D
@       IN      SOA     ns.rpi.dev. admin.rpi.dev. (
                2007062001
                28800
                604800
                604800
                86400
)
         IN      NS      ns.rpi.dev.
1        IN      PTR     gw.rpi.dev.
169      IN      PTR     ubuntudesktop.rpi.dev.
129      IN      PTR     miphone.rpi.dev.
```

***/etc/bind/named.conf.options***

```
options {
        directory "/var/cache/bind";

        // If there is a firewall between you and nameservers you want
        // to talk to, you may need to fix the firewall to allow multiple
        // ports to talk.  See http://www.kb.cert.org/vuls/id/800113

        // If your ISP provided one or more IP addresses for stable
        // nameservers, you probably want to use them as forwarders.
        // Uncomment the following block, and insert the addresses replacing
        // the all-0's placeholder.

         forwarders {
         //     0.0.0.0;
         202.53.9.2;
         202.53.9.3;
         };
//=======
        // If BIND logs error messages about the root key being expired,
        // you will need to update your keys.  See https://www.isc.org/bind-keys

//=======
        dnssec-validation auto;

        auth-nxdomain no;    # conform to RFC1035
        listen-on-v6 { any; };
};
```

Where ***202.53.9.2, 202.53.9.3*** are my ISP DNS IP

***/etc/resolv.conf***

```
# Generated by resolvconf
nameserver 192.168.31.1

Search rpi.dev
nameserver 192.168.31.164
```

after this I restarted the Bind by doing the following command in raspberry pi:

```
sudo /etc/init.d/bind9 restart
```

Now I did this in raspberry pi

```
dig rpi.dev
```

I got the following result

```
; <<>> DiG 9.9.5-9+deb8u13-Raspbian <<>> rpi.dev
;; global options: +cmd
;; Got answer:
;; ->>HEADER<<- opcode: QUERY, status: NOERROR, id: 27640
;; flags: qr rd ra; QUERY: 1, ANSWER: 1, AUTHORITY: 0, ADDITIONAL: 1

;; OPT PSEUDOSECTION:
; EDNS: version: 0, flags:; udp: 4096
;; QUESTION SECTION:
;rpi.dev.           IN  A

;; ANSWER SECTION:
rpi.dev.        30  IN  A   127.0.53.53

;; Query time: 16 msec
;; SERVER: 192.168.31.1#53(192.168.31.1)
;; WHEN: Wed Oct 04 19:30:25 UTC 2017
;; MSG SIZE  rcvd: 52
```

Then did this

```
nslookup gw
```

I got the following output

```
Server:     192.168.31.1
Address:    192.168.31.1#53

Non-authoritative answer:
*** Can't find gw: No answer
```

Then I tried to open ***rpi.dev*** in my smartphone and I got the following output: ***This site can't be reached"

From ubuntu laptop's ***/etc/hosts*** file, I commented the line where I entered IP address with rpi.dev i.e ***#192.168.31.164    rpi.dev***, after this I pinged rpi.dev on ubuntu terminal and it is returning this ip address: ***127.0.53.53**

```
64 bytes from 127.0.53.53: icmp_seq=1 ttl=64 time=0.014 ms
```

Is there something that Im missing or do I need to do more actions. Please help.

Comment: .local runs on avasi and unfortunately it is not working in android phones. Tried installing Bonjour browser and it also didn't work.